# Python - react to custom keyboard interrupt

Tags: python, console, chat, interrupt

I am writing python chatbot that displays output through console. Every half second it asks server for updates, and responds to message. In the console I can see chat log.

This is sufficient in most cases, however, sometimes I want to interrupt normal workflow and write custom chat answer myself. I would love to be able to press a button (or combination) that would switch to "custom reply mode". What is the best way to do that, or achieve similar result?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `select.select()` on `sys.stdin` will allow you to check if a key has been pressed at the terminal.

Comment: Could you give example of select.select() parameters? I am googling and I only find bugs related to windows (I am using UNIX console).

which kind of parameter should I need - rlist, wlist or xlist?

thanks!

Comment: Great! This works quite well:

 def heardEnter():
  i,o,e = select.select([sys.stdin],[],[],1)
  for s in i:
   if s == sys.stdin:
    input = sys.stdin.readline()
    return True
  return False

Answer (score 1):

Given the comments in the previous answer, you need a non-blocking function to tell whether any keys were pressed rather than something that triggers as soon as the key was pressed.

I would therefore recommend using some of the terminal APIs available on your OS.  Typically this would be curses or the win32 console API.  However, I have written a common wrapper to both in [asciimatics](https://github.com/peterbrittain/asciimatics).  The `get_event()` method on the `Screen` should provide a simple cross-platform way of getting mouse and keyboard events.  To see if it was a keyboard event, check the type of returned event.  If there was no event, you'll get a return code of `None`, but if it was a key pressed, you'll get  `KeyboardEvent`.